# SpriteKitでnode同士がすり抜けてしまう。

Tags: swift, spritekit

physicalbodyを設定した、spriteNode同士が、衝突の際に常に跳ね返って欲しいのに、時々すり抜けてしまいます。

一方をSKAction.moveで移動し、他方にぶつけた時に、跳ね返る時と、すり抜ける時があります。

常に跳ね返るようにするにはどうすれば良いですか？

下の画像の赤い四角が”box”です。

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    private var box : SKSpriteNode!
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        if let b = self.childNode(withName: "box") {
            box = b as? SKSpriteNode
        }
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let move = SKAction.moveTo(y: 100, duration: 0.1)
        box?.run(move)
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered
    }
}
```

[image: GameScene.sks]

[GameScene.sks]

Comment: 衝突処理や接触判定がうまくいかないのは大抵は`categoryBitMask`や`collisionBitMask`の設定ミスなのですが、あなたの書かれたような「時々すり抜けてしまいます」と言うのを再現するのは難しいです。ぜひ実際のコードをお示しください。もし、あなたのコードがすでに本番に近く長すぎるのなら、是非、問題を再現できるような最小限のコードを模索してください。その過程でご自身の誤りを見つけられる方も多いです。

Comment: コードの提示ありがとうございます。ほとんどの設定をsksエディタ上でやっておられるようですが、「跳ね返る時」もあると言うことなので、「Physics Definition」の設定は一通り行われているものと仮定します。考えられる可能性としては、「移動の速度が早すぎるのではないか」と言うことです。`let move = SKAction.moveTo(y: 100, duration: 0.1)`の中の`0.1`の値を少しずつ増やしてみてください。ある値から急に「必ず跳ね返る」ようになりませんか?